# Method results not displayed in Console

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, testng

I have two methods

```
1.public void VerifyLoan()
2.public void VerifyPersonalInfo
```

After running the tests, I see only the Results of `VerifyLoan()` as Passes  in  my Console. But the results of the other method `public void VerifyPersonalInfo` are not displayed

Attached my Code and Console below

```
 @BeforeTest    
 public void beforetest()
 {
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chromedriver"," E:\\chromedriver.exe");
        driver = new ChromeDriver();
        String baseurl = "https://staging.centum.no/skjema";
        driver.get(baseurl);
        driver.manage().window().maximize();
 }

@Test
public void VerifyLoan() throws InterruptedException
{
        Locators loan = new Locators(driver);
        loan.LoanPurpose();
}

public void VerifyPersonalInfo() 
{
        Locators Info = new Locators(driver);
        Info.PersonalInfo();
}

@AfterTest
public void aftertest()
{
}
```

Console Output

```
Starting ChromeDriver 2.34.522940 (1a76f96f66e3ca7b8e57d503b4dd3bccfba87af1) on port 33313
Only local connections are allowed.
PASSED: VerifyLoan

===============================================
    Default test
    Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Skips: 0
===============================================


===============================================
Default suite
Total tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Ski
```

Comment: did you try to add @Test above "public void VerifyPersonalInfo()" too?

Comment: only method annotated with Test tag is displayed in the console. please add @Test tag to the required method.

Comment: Above comments are the answer to your question

Answer (score 0):

please try the following code

```
 @BeforeTest   
 public void beforetest() 
 {
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chromedriver"," E:\\chromedriver.exe");
        driver = new ChromeDriver();
        String baseurl = "https://staging.centum.no/skjema";
        driver.get(baseurl);
        driver.manage().window().maximize();
 }

@Test(priority=1)
public void VerifyLoan() throws InterruptedException
{
        Locators loan = new Locators(driver);
        loan.LoanPurpose();
}

@Test(priority=2)
public void VerifyPersonalInfo() 
{
        Locators Info = new Locators(driver);
        Info.PersonalInfo();
}

@AfterTest
public void aftertest()
{
}
```